# How can I find the first difference between two strings in Python?

Tags: python, difflib

Let's say I have:

```
a = 'abcde'
b = 'ab34e'
```

How can I get printed out that the difference in a is c,d and in b is 3,4?
Also would it be possible to also the get the index of those?

I know I should use difflib, but the furthest I've got is with this overly complex code from this website: https://towardsdatascience.com/side-by-side-comparison-of-strings-in-python-b9491ac858

and it doesn't even do what I want to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
a = "abcde"
b = "ab2de"

for index, char in enumerate(a):
    if not b[index] == char:
        print(f"First mismatch on index {index}: {char} is not {b[index]}")
```

Would print: `First mismatch on index 2: c is not 2`

Another possibility would be to create a list of 3-way-tuples, where the first element would be the index, the second element would be the char in `a` and the third element would be the char in `b`:

```
a = "abcde"
b = "ab23e"
print([(index, char, b[index]) for index, char in enumerate(a) if not b[index] == char])
```

Would result in `[(2, 'c', '2'), (3, 'd', '3')]`

Comment: but if there was already a 2 before in string a would this work?
like:
a = 2abcde
b = 2ab2de

Comment: This compares char by char the strings. So, it checks if the first letter is the same, the second letter is the same, etc. It doesn't matter if characters are more than once present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Answer

For a -b:

```
a_diff  = [i for i in set(a) if i not in set(b) ]
```

for b -a:

```
b_diff = [i for i in set(b) if i not in set(a) ]
```

Combine the two results to get aggregate diff:

```
a_diff + b_diff
```

### My output:

[image]

Comment: This solution only shows which characters are in A but not B (or vice versa), but does not address the question on where those differences are in the strings.

Comment: Made the changes to incorporate it. Thanks

Comment: That's not what I meant. The question was: how can we get the differences between string a and b on a per character basis. You make it a set, inherently losing any information on positions of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use zip in the for loop to handle size difference in the two lists at the same time. Otherwise you could run into an index error.

```
a = "abcde3asdfat"
b = "ab2de2asdfqT"

count = 0
for string_a, string_b in zip(a, b):
    if string_a not in string_b:
        print(f'{string_a} mismatched {string_b} at index {count}')
    count += 1
```